# Agregar una línea debajo de un TextView (XML)

Tags: android, textview

Que tal a todos estoy intentando agregar una línea debajo de mi `TextView` y el problema que encuentro es que cuando éste tiene más de una línea..
tengo un `layer-list`

si es que tiene más de una línea aparece abajo.. mi primera opción fue agregar un cuadro y desaparecer el lado de izquierda, derecha y arriba, para sólo obtener el de abajo..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="-2dp"
            android:right="-2dp"
            android:top="-2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#FF000000" />

                <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

                <padding android:left="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Y mi resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi segunda opción que encontré con un `shape`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#4fa5d5" />
</shape>
```

Y me resultado fue este 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es lograr es poner poner una línea debajo de cada línea de texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que deseas realizar es un subrayado del texto, para realizarlo existen de diversas formas:

Una forma es usando un **[SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)**:

```
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SpannableString mitextoU = new SpannableString("Mamut chiquito");
        mitextoU.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mitextoU.length(), 0);
        textView.setText(mitextoU);
```

teniendo como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

otra opción es cargando el texto desde `strings.xml` (muy importante el CDATA) ,

```
<string name="mi_mensaje"><![CDATA[Este es un <u>Mamut chiquito</u>]]></string>
```

y cargando el texto al `TextView` mediante:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.mi_mensaje)));
```

teniendo como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

otra opción es escribiendo el texto dentro del contenedor `<u>` y aplicar la transformación Html:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Este es un <u>Mamut chiquito</u>"));
```

teniendo como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

otra opción usando [**setPaintFlags()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setPaintFlags(int)) :

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
textView.setText("Mamut chiquito");
```

teniendo como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Listo ! Gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Que bien que fue de ayuda mi post, muchos saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Desde el `string` lo colocas de esta manera:

```
<string name="mi_texto"><u>texto</u></string>
```

y despues lo colocas en tu `textview`:

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es crear una línea debajo de algún elemento lo que puedes hacer es usar un View con 1dp de grosor (o más, depende de cuánto lo quieras de alto).

```
<View 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="1dp"       
   android:background="#000" />
```

En cambio, si lo que quieres es subrayar el texto de un textView, como adición a lo que indica @Elenasys puedes usar una flag:

```
tuTextView.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
tuTextView.setText("Subrayemos el texto");
```

donde `tuTextView` es el `textView` donde quieres que el texto aparezca subrayado.

Comment: Si men eso lo hago siempre, pero lo que intento es que dentro del TextView cada línea de texto tenga abajo como un subrayado, de todas formas gracias por tu alternativa.

Comment: @marlonpya ¿Has probado la segunda opción de la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

En el xml del TextView agregala siguiente linea

```
            android:autoLink="phone"
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], editar tu aporte y agregar el por que de esta recomendación la haría más fácil de comprender. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar debajo de del contener de tu texto (LinearLayout):

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Es importante que la orientación del contenedor padre sea vertical

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```