# Negrita en una parte de un TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Buenas, quería saber si en un `TextView` se podría poner solo una parte de este en negrita, como por ejemplo:

Hola **mundo**, me llamo **Pepe**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existen varias formas para realizar esto (dos son similares a esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32572/agregar-una-l%C3%ADnea-debajo-de-un-textview-xml/32580#32580) pero ahora utilizarías `<b>`).

Una opción es cargando el texto desde el texto desde `Strings.xml` y usando `Html.fromHtml()`, en este caso es muy importante usar el `CDATA` ,

```
<string name="mi_mensaje"><![CDATA[Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b>]]></string>
```

y cargando el texto al `TextView` mediante:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.mi_mensaje)));
```

---

También se puede cargar el texto sin usar `CATA`, para este caso se usa el método [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()), definimos de esta forma la cadena dentro de `Strings.xml`:

```
<string name="mi_mensaje">Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b></string>
```

y lo cargamos mediante el método [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()):

```
textView.setText(getText(R.string.mi_mensaje));
```

---

otra opción es escribir directamente dentro del `textView` tu texto y aplicar la transformación [Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b>"));
```

---

La tercera opción es usando [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) y definiendo un [StyleSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html) con estilo `bold` para las palabras en negrita, en esta opción tienes que calcular el indice de inicio y fin de la o las palabras a la cuales deseas aplicar el estilo :

```
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    SpannableString miTexto = new SpannableString("Hola mundo, me llamo Pepe");
    StyleSpan boldSpan1 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    StyleSpan boldSpan2 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    miTexto.setSpan(boldSpan1, 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    miTexto.setSpan(boldSpan2, 20, miTexto.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(miTexto);
```

obteniendo con las 3 opciones el mismo resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Usando un .xml o un .json puedes agregar código html y parsear el valor para que sea representado en tu vista, en el caso de un xml no olvides agregar el contenedor `<![CDATA`

#### Usando un XML

```
<texto><![CDATA[Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b>]]></texto>
```

#### Usando un .json

```
{
    "texto": "Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b>", 
}
```

Comment: Me encanta la parte de "editando..." jaja

Comment: Muy útil la primera opción, no la conocía y estuve indagando sobre esto hace unos días, +1

Comment: @Error404 haha si amigo, sucede que anteriormente dejaba sin completar una respuesta porque me tenia que ocupar en otras tareas y al regresar estaba lleno de negativas calificaciones =P.

Comment: @Elenasys Eso me ha pasado a mí jaja Iba a ponerlas todas pero me tenía que ir y he puesto la que me sabía la sintaxis. Las otras tenía que haber mirado la documentación porque no sabía que caracteres exactos tenía el CDATA o el SpannableString. Luego cuando he vuelto ya he visto que estaba la tuya así que no la he editado :D

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar las etiquetas de HTML para este propósito. Por ejemplo, puedes realizar:

```
String tuString = "Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b">; 
tuTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(tuString));
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo, ahora comento como ha ido. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @sioesi Justo lo había editado yo. Has hecho edit del edit ^^

Comment: jajaja disculpa! estaba escribiendo la respuesta y me ganaste :P saludos @Error404

Comment: @borjis Vale, cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar ^^

Comment: @Error404 funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias ^^. Marco como respuesta más útil la de Elenasys que está más completa.

Comment: @borjis Sin problemas :)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso del objeto `Html` y su método `fromHtml` para darle **negrita** a las palabras necesarias en tu `string`

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b>."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, veo que todas las respuestas que te proporcionan es haciendo uso de `HTML` las cuales son muy buena elección, en esta respuesta te propongo que hagas uso de **SpannableStringBuilder** por si algún día quieres aplicarlo de otra forma :D

```
final SpannableStringBuilder texto= new SpannableStringBuilder("Tu texto");

final StyleSpan letraEnNegrita= new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // Para hacer negrita

texto.setSpan(letraEnNegrita, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // Convierte los primeros 4 caracteres en negrita, tu puedes decirle cuantos caracteres :)
tuTextview.setText(texto);
```

Comment: Elenasys lo comentó y ya lo ha editado y ha puesto un ejemplo ^^ muchas gracias de todas maneras.

Answer (score 2):

Cata mi clase, extiende de TextView permitiendo añadir HTML y el efecto fade-in-out al cambiar el valor del texto:

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by efraespada on 15/04/2016.
 */
public class SuperTextView extends TextView {

    private boolean ready;
    private int finalOpacity;

    public SuperTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        ready = false;
        finalOpacity = 255;
        addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(this));
    }

    public SuperTextView(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        ready = false;
        finalOpacity = 255;
        addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(this));
    }

    public SuperTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ready = false;
        finalOpacity = 255;
        addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(this));
    }

    public SuperTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ready = false;
        finalOpacity = 255;
        addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        if (ready && getText() != null && text != null) {
            String toChange = (String) text.toString();
            String myText = "" + getText();

            if (!myText.equals(Html.fromHtml(toChange).toString()))
                super.setText((CharSequence) Html.fromHtml(toChange), type);
        } else {

            String r;

            try {
                r = Html.fromHtml((String) text).toString();
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                r = text.toString();
            }

            CharSequence t = (CharSequence) r;

            super.setText(t, type);
        }
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence text, int opacity) {
        if (opacity >= 0 && opacity <= 255) finalOpacity = opacity;

        if (ready && getText() != null && text != null) {
            String toChange = (String) text.toString();
            String myText = "" + getText();
            CharSequence t = (CharSequence) Html.fromHtml(toChange);
            if (!myText.equals(Html.fromHtml(toChange).toString())) super.setText((CharSequence) Html.fromHtml(toChange), null);
        } else super.setText((CharSequence) Html.fromHtml((String) text), null);
    }

    public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private TextView element;
        private Integer[] rgb;

        public CustomTextWatcher(TextView element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            final int from = getAlpha(element.getCurrentTextColor()), to = 0;

            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);   // animate from 0 to 1
            anim.setDuration(600);                              // for 300 ms

            rgb = parseColor(element.getCurrentTextColor());
            final int[] alpha  = new int[1];                  // transition color
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    alpha[0] = (int) (from + (to - from)*animation.getAnimatedFraction());
                    element.setTextColor(Color.argb(alpha[0], rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
                }
            });

            anim.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Log.e("Text","change:" + getCurrentTextColor());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ready = true;
            final int from = 0, to = finalOpacity;

            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);   // animate from 0 to 1
            anim.setDuration(600);                              // for 300 ms

            final int[] alpha  = new int[1];                  // transition color
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    alpha[0] = (int) (from + (to - from)*animation.getAnimatedFraction());
                    element.setTextColor(Color.argb(alpha[0], rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
                }


            });

            anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    finalOpacity = 255;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    finalOpacity = 255;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    finalOpacity = 255;
                }
            });

            anim.start();
        }

        public Integer[] parseColor(int value) {
            Integer[] rgb = new Integer[3];

            String hexColor = String.format("%06X", (0xFFFFFF & value));

            int color = (int)Long.parseLong(hexColor, 16);
            rgb[0] = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
            rgb[1] = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
            rgb[2] = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;

            return rgb;
        }

        public int getAlpha(int value) {
            return new ColorDrawable(value).getAlpha();
        }
    }
}
```

Para añadirlo a tu XML:

```
<com.example.SuperTextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Añade mediante programación texto al objeto.