# Poner una palabra en negrita en un texto XML

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

He estado mirando y he visto varias soluciones pero todas pasan por hacer algo fuera del `TextView`, por ejemplo para usar separación en renglones yo uso `\n` no hay algo similar para poner una sola palabra (o varias distintas) en negrita?
En este caso para probar, poner ***Texto2*** en negrita.

```
<TextView
    android:text="Texto 1
    \n
    Texto2
    \n
    Texto3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

Comment: puedo decir que esta pregunta podría estar respondida, revisa el enlace que pongo en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

existen varias formas, por ejemplo utilizando en tag de letra bold `<b>`, cargando el texto desde strings.xml:

```
<string name="mi_mensaje"><![CDATA[Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b>]]></string>
```

y cargando el texto al `TextView` mediante:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.mi_mensaje)));
```

revisa esta respuesta:

[Negrita en una parte de un TextView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34401/negrita-en-una-parte-de-un-textview/34402#34402)

Comment: Si, @Jorgesys vi esta misma respuesta pero mi pregunta es si puedo hacerlo desde el `TextView` sin pasar por otros archivos

Comment: android:textStyle="bold" unicamente aplica para todo el texto si deseas varias palabras hay dos opciones textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hola <b>mundo</b>, me llamo <b>Pepe</b>"));
 o usando SpannableString.

Comment: Ya conozco el método que me comentas, pero mi pregunta es si puedo poner una palabra (no toda la frase) en negrita desde `TextView`, sin necesidad de pasar por la `clase` ni `string`, es posible? @Jorgesys

Comment: Tiene que ser mediante las 2 opciones que menciono SpannableString o agregar código html  y resolverlo mediante Html.fromHtml()

Comment: Bien, era eso lo que quería saber, si había posibilidad de hacerlo mediante el `TextView` sin pasar por la `clase` o `string` queda claro entonces! Gracias @Jorgesys