# Poner una palabra en negrita de un TextoView XML Android Studio

Tags: xml, textview

Hola amigos estoy haciendo una aplicación en android studio (soy muy novato) y tengo un problema. En el texto "Este es un ejemplo de mi problema" quisiera poner solamente la palabra "ejemplo" en negrita pero no se como hacerlo.

Tendría que quedar así:

> Este es un **ejemplo** de mi problema.

Este es mi codigo espero me puedan ayudar

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Este es un ejemplo de mi problema"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="216dp" />
```

He intentado utilizar `<b>ejemplo</b>` pero no pasa nada
y también intente con: `android:textStyle="bold|italic"` pero esto pone todo en negritas y yo solo quiero una palabra.

Comment: ya se ha respondido [Palabra en negritas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48970/poner-una-palabra-en-negrita-en-un-texto-xml?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería utilizar un textView solo para el elemento en negrita y poner la propiedade

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus respuestas, lo solucioné así:

```
private TextView casilla;
casilla = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV_nota1);
casilla.setText(Html.fromHtml("Este es un <b>ejemplo</b> de mi problema."));
```

No se si sea la mejor opción pero de momento me saca del apuro