# Cambiar el color de un TextView solo a unos determinados caracteres

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo este `TextView`:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView17"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean dapibus sem vel magna venenatis, nec tempus enim mattis. Proin tristique faucibus nisl eget volutpat."
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Lo que necesito es poner `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` en verde y lo demás en negro (Por defecto).

Es posible hacerlo mediante código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es cambiar el color de un trozo del texto que tienes dentro del XML puedes reemplazar un trozo de texto mediante la función `replace` y utilizar un `SpannableString` para ello.

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
SpannableString texto = textview.getText().toString();
texto = texto.replace("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "<font color=#00b300>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</font>");
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText));
```

Comment: El problema es que el color que tengo que usar le tengo en el archivo `/values/colors.xml`  por lo demás seria perfecta tu solución

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper No hay problema, podrías hacer `"<font color=" + 
 ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tuColorPersonalizado) + ">Lorem ipsum...`

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, todo perfecto

Answer (score 2):

Lo he conseguido con este código, no es exactamente como queria pero funciona:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

SpannableString str1= new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, str1.length(), 0);
builder.append(str1);

SpannableString str2= new SpannableString(", consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean dapibus sem vel magna venenatis, nec tempus enim mattis. Proin tristique faucibus nisl eget volutpat.");
str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, str2.length(), 0);
builder.append(str2);

TextView tv = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.punto1);
tv.setText( builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Cuando defines el Span, indicas el ForegroundColorSpan, inicio y final para aplicarlo, revisa mi respuesta donde explico los parametros.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede realizar de diversas formas,

**1)** Mediante el método `Html.fromHtml()` y definiendo en  `strings.xml` el texto a cambiar el color

```
 <string name="mi_mensaje"><![CDATA[Hola <font color=#FF0040>StackOverflow.com</font>, como te encuentras el día de hoy!]]></string>
```

de esta forma realizas el cambio:

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.mi_mensaje),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.mi_mensaje)));
    }
```

**2)** Definiendo el texto directamente, usando `Html.fromHtml()`:

```
String mensaje = "Hola <font color=#FF0040>StackOverflow.com</font>, como te encuentras el día de hoy!";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mensaje,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mensaje));
}
```

**3)** Usando un `SpannableString`, definiendo un `Span` con el color deseado :

```
SpannableString mensaje = new SpannableString("Hola StackOverflow.com, como te encuentras el día de hoy!");
ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0040"));// Puedes usar tambien .. new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED); 
mensaje.setSpan(colorSpan, 5, 22, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(mensaje);
```

El método [setSpan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int))  define como parametros:

- El objeto `ForegroundColorSpan`.
- El inicio en la cadena de caracteres a aplicar el span.
- El final en la cadena de caracteres a aplicar el span.
- Las banderas, en este caso [SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE), que indica Expandir para incluir el texto insertado en su punto inicial o final.

Las 3 opciones obtienen como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

similar a lo que se tiene en esta  respuesta:
[Negrita en una parte de un TextView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34401/negrita-en-una-parte-de-un-textview/34403#34403)