# Texto de dos colores en TextView Android

Tags: android, textview

estoy haciendo una app y necesito que en el textView se debería de mostrar los comandos at que envió al exterior y también se tiene que mostrar las respuestas,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para diferenciar cual es interrogación y cual es respuestas, por eso yo necesito cambiar el color del texto dependiendo si esta sale o entra al dispositivo, por defecto las respuestas están configuradas en el layout xml a color azul, usando este codigo yo intento cambiar solo las preguntas a color rojo, pero hay errores y no puedo lograr lo que necesito

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1_ReadValues);
    mTextoEditor1 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.et1_WriteValues ) ;
    mTextoEditor2 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.et2_WriteValues ) ;
    mBotonSend1 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt1_SendButton ) ;
    mBotonSend2 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt2_SendButton ) ;

    mBotonSend1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTextoEditor1.length() != 0x00){

                String bufferTXD1 = mTextoEditor1.getText().toString() + "\r" + "\n";
                mDumpTextView.append(bufferTXD1);
                mTextoEditor1.setText( "" );

            }
        }
    } );

    mBotonSend2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTextoEditor2.length() != 0x00){

                String bufferTXD2 = mTextoEditor2.getText().toString() + "\r" + "\n";
                mDumpTextView.append(bufferTXD2);

                nroBuffer = mDumpTextView.length();
                nroChar = bufferTXD2.length();
                starChar = nroBuffer - nroChar;
                nroChar = nroChar - 2;
                endChar = nroBuffer - nroChar;

                SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

                SpannableString textColor = new SpannableString(bufferTXD2);
                textColor.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), starChar, endChar, 0);
                builder.append(textColor);


                mTextoEditor2.setText( "" );
            }
        }
    } );

}
```

}

Alguien me podria decir como hacerlo, gracias.

---

> Si deseas usar un SpannableString, puedes realizarlo de esta forma, definiendo usar el color rojo ("#FF0000") o el azul ("#0000FF") ;

Debe de haber algún error, por que el texto de entrada y salida sale del color (azul), inclusive ya he cambiado a color, rojo, verde, amarillo.. siempres sale azul.

Comment: Como determinas cual es Rojo y cual Azul ?

Comment: No entiendo todos los cálculos que haces con variables como `nroBuffer` o `norChar`, etc. ¿Acaso el texto que debe ir en rojo )y en azul) no viene aparte, o es que viene mezclado con más cosas y por eso intentas esos cálculos extraños? La solución parece fácil, pero no dices como viene tu información y así es difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ok el problema es que siempre sale Rojo, como determinas si es entrada o salida en tu código? @W1II

Comment: El texto de color azul  son las respuestas que vienen del exterior a través del puerto usb y los los rojos son las preguntas que salen, el calculo que hago de las variables es por que el textview es una consola en la que deben de mostrar preguntas y respuestas y esto depende solo del usuario, no son textos fijos; mTextoEditor1=respuestas, mTextoEditor2=preguntas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor de interrogación que sería de color azul puedes agregar el contenedor `<font>` de html definiendo el color azul:

```
"<font color=#0000FF>" + valor + "</font>";
```

en el caso de la repuesta define el color rojo:

```
"<font color=#FF0000>" + valor + "</font>";
```

y al mostrar en tu `TextView` el texto usa el método `Html.fromHtml(...)`, de esta forma se mostrará el texto con el color deseado.

```
   myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(valor));
```

Si deseas usar un [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString), puedes realizarlo de esta forma, definiendo usar el color rojo (`"#FF0000"`) o el azul (`"#0000FF"`) ;

```
  ... 
  SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(); 

  SpannableString textColor = new SpannableString(bufferTXD2);
  ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));// Puedes usar tambien .. new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
  textColor.setSpan(colorSpan, 0, bufferTXD2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

  builder.append(textColor);

  mTextoEditor2.setText( builder );
  ...
```

---

Revisa esta información relacionada:

[Cambiar el color de un TextView solo a unos determinados caracteres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74991/cambiar-el-color-de-un-textview-solo-a-unos-determinados-caracteres/74996#74996)

[Negrita en una parte de un TextView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34401/negrita-en-una-parte-de-un-textview/34403#34403)

Comment: Se puede hacer perfectamente con `SpannableString` también. Lo que pasa es que en la pregunta no es claro si el texto que debería en rojo y en azul viene aparte o si viene mezclado. Él intenta unos cálculos extraños que me confunden.

Comment: los textos vienen por separado mTextoEditor1=respuestas, mTextoEditor2=preguntas; según el código que he publicado, para simular tengo dos textEdit (et1_WriteValues, et2_WriteValues)