# Texto de ListView de dos colores

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una app que envía y recibe datos y estos datos son mostrados en una `ListView` pero me gustaría si se puede cambiar el color del texto de tal los textos recibidos (RX...) sean de color y los textos (TX...) sean de otro color diferente, se puede hacer esto? como?.

Aquí esta mi código, he intentado usar `Html.fromHtml` pero no funciono.

```
//* Aqui Transmite datos
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    arrayList.add("TX: " + message);                        
    //arrayList.add( Html.fromHtml( redB +  "TX: " + message + colorEnd ) );
    if (mTcpClient != null) {
        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);                    
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                        
    editText.setText("");
  }
});
.
.

//* Aqui Recibe datos
@Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   arrayList.add("RX: " + values[0]);                
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                  
}
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estas intentando cambiar el color a los textos? ¿A la letra? ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Necesito cambiar el color del texto a todos los texto que son Transmitidos

Comment: @W1ll trata lo que agregue en mi respuesta, es similar a lo que habías preguntado anteriormente solo agrega los contenedores que definen el color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si revisa una pregunta que realizaste anteriormente:

[Texto de dos colores en TextView Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209682/texto-de-dos-colores-en-textview-android)

debes agregar los contenedores html donde se define el color, cuando agregas los valores en el `ArrayList` para los textos de "transmisión":

```
 // arrayList.add("TX: " + message); 
 //Color Rojo
  arrayList.add("<font color=#FF0000>TX: " + message + "</font>");
```

y para los textos de "recepción"

```
  //arrayList.add("RX: " + values[0]);       
  //Color azul
  arrayList.add("<font color=#0000FF>RX: " + values[0] + "</font>");
```

Cuando agregues los textos en tus `TextView` usa `Html.fromHtml()` :

```
 myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(valorArralist));
```

Answer (score 1):

la solucion a esto es simple, debes crear un adapter al que le ingreses itemns/componentes y no texto unicamente.
Para hacer esto primero debes crear tu layout (UI_componente)

```
<!-- Definis el texto y proximamente el color-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ejemplo"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Luego solo queda agregar el adapter a tu ListView

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.itemListView, listItems){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            /*ELEJIS EL COLOR APLICANDO LA LOGICA QUE NECESITES*/
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            return view;
        }
    };

    /*SETEAS EL ADAPTER*/
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```