# Como dar formato a un texto HTML en android?

Tags: android

Estoy consumiendo la API de wordpress y me devuelve el texto en formato HTML por ejemplo :

```html
<p>Por Nora Moreno</p>    
    
    <p>Esta tarde el alcalde San Salvador, Ernesto Muyshondt, recibió  a la ministra de Desarrollo Local, María Chichilco, para firmar un convenio de ejecución del programa de Emprendimiento Solidario. </p>
    
    
    
    <p>“Tenemos el honor de subscribir este convenio de ejecución del Programa de Emprendimiento Solidario. Esperamos que con esta nueva administración poder llevar el FISDL a ser un ministerio&#8221;, dijo el mandatario. </p>
    
    
    
    <p>De igual manera expreso que como alcaldía se comprometerán a trabajar en equipo. &#8220;Nos comprometemos a sumar esfuerzos para contribuir a este programa y beneficiar a los jóvenes de las comunidades que han sido declaradas como  prioritarias en el Plan El Salvador seguro”, mencionó.</p>
```

EL detalle es que al darle formato en android con la funcion:

```
Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(txtHtml).toString())
```

Me nuestra ex texto sin saltos de linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado lo siguiente sin obtener resultado:

```
String txtHtml = noticia.getCuerpo().replace("<p>","<br>");


String txtHtml = noticia.getCuerpo().replace("<p>","\n");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu texto original debería representarse correctamente usando el método `Html.fromHtml(...)`:

```
<p>Por Nora Moreno</p>    

<p>Esta tarde el alcalde San Salvador, Ernesto Muyshondt, recibió  a la ministra de Desarrollo Local, María Chichilco, para firmar un convenio de ejecución del programa de Emprendimiento Solidario. </p>



<p>“Tenemos el honor de subscribir este convenio de ejecución del Programa de Emprendimiento Solidario. Esperamos que con esta nueva administración poder llevar el FISDL a ser un ministerio&#8221;, dijo el mandatario. </p>



<p>De igual manera expreso que como alcaldía se comprometerán a trabajar en equipo. &#8220;Nos comprometemos a sumar esfuerzos para contribuir a este programa y beneficiar a los jóvenes de las comunidades que han sido declaradas como  prioritarias en el Plan El Salvador seguro”, mencionó.</p>
```

El problema en realidad se debe a que  únicamente debes convertir la cadena a su representación html y no realizar posteriormente más conversiones, ya que es aquí donde se esta perdiendo información.

Realiza lo siguiente:

```
//String textoConFormato = Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(txtHtml).toString());
String textoConFormato = Html.fromHtml(txtHtml);
```

con esto obtendrás el resultado deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Relacionados:

[TextView con dos colores de texto en Android usando Html.fromHtml()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/222300/textview-con-dos-colores-de-texto-en-android)

[Texto de ListView de dos colores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241154/texto-de-listview-de-dos-colores?rq=1)

Comment: perfecto me funciono, muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente @IgmerRodriguez saludos!