# Como cambiar el color de un elemento tipo TextView desde MainActivity.java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, textview, color

Como puedo cambiar el color de un elemento TextView mediante la pulsación de un botón.

De momento he utilizado este código:

```
private Button btnRojo;
private Button btnVerde;
private Button btnAzul;
private TextView textoPrueba;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnRojo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRojo);
    textoPrueba = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrueba);

    btnRojo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "boton rojo pulsado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Aqui es donde entiendo que deberia ir el cambio de la propiedad del TextView
        }
    });
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado con la linea

```
textoPrueba.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Hola Forrest Gant, me alegro que encontraras una respuesta a tu pregunta y que la hayas compartido con la comunidad. Te comento que esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido, sería ideal si pudieras añadir algo más de detalle para que esté más completa, por ejemplo, ¿qué hace `setTextColor`? ¿dónde lo pusiste en el código? ¿hay alguna página que usaste como referencia para encontrar la solución? Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

#### ¿Como cambiar el color del texto dentro de un TextView?

Para cambiar el color dentro de tu TextView debes usar el método **[setTextColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextColor(int))**

Hay varias formas de realizarlo:

• Puedes usar un color definido en la clase [**Color**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#constants_1)

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

---

• Puedes usar un color hexadecimal y convertirlo mediante `Color.parseColor()` :

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

---

• Puedes usar también la definición de un color en RGB usando

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
```

---

• Puedes usar un color definido dentro de `colors.xml`, definelo de esta forma :

```
   <color name="myRedColor">#FF0000</color>
```

y definelo a tu `TextView` de esta forma mediante su nombre:

```
 textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.myRedColor));
```

---

• Incluso puedes cambiar el color de algunos caracteres dentro de tu `TextView`.

[Texto de dos colores en TextView Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209682/texto-de-dos-colores-en-textview-android)