# Texto en negrita desde un json

Tags: android, android-studio, json

Hay alguna manera de hacer que una fracción de texto en un json  en Android Studio 2.3 se ponga en negrita, como mismo se hacen los saltos de linea.

tengo este json:

```
{
"array_texto":[
    {
    "texto"":"Hola mundo",
    "texto":"Esto es un hola mundo"
    }
]
}
```

leo el json desde la carpeta raw con este codigo:

```
 public String LeerFicheroRAW (InputStream fraw){
        String linea = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader brin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fraw));

            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = brin.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            linea = sBuilder.toString();
            fraw.close();
            Log.i("Ficheros", "Fichero RAW leido!");
            Log.i("Ficheros", "Texto: " + linea);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Ficheros", "Error al leer fichero desde recurso raw");
        }
        return linea;
    }
```

en la actividad principal deserializo el json y lo muestro en el texview asi:

```
final InputStream fraw = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.consti);
        String text = aux.LeerFicheroRAW(fraw);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        json = gson.fromJson(text, Clase_generica.class);
 String texto = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array_texto.size(); i++) {
            texto = texto.concat(getArraytexto.get(i).getTexto());
            texto = texto.concat("\n\n");
        }
 textview.setText(texto);
```

lo que quiero saber es si desde el archivo json puede hacer que el texto ya venga en negrita por defecto y aparesca asi:

**Hola mundo:**
Esto es un hola mundo

porque por ejemplo si en el archivo json tengo \n asi:

```
 {
    "array_texto":[
        {
        "texto"":"Hola mundo",
        "texto":"Esto es\n un hola mundo"
        }
    ]
    }
```

entoncesd aparece asi cuando se muestra en el texview:

Hola mundo

Esto es

un hola mundo

como mismo el IDE reconoce que "\n" es un salto de linea, hay algo con lo que pueda especificar que texto quiro que valla en negrita. Alguna idea?

Comment: Si es código que se va a insertar en una página web, puedes directamente crear algo como `{"texto": "<strong>Hola mundo</strong>"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas realizar esto:

**Hola mundo**: Esto es un hola mundo

a partir del .json que propones, si puedes editar la respuesta que obtienes puedes agregar los tags html para letra bold : `<b>`

```
 {
    "array_texto":[
        {
        "texto"":"<b>Hola mundo</b>",
        "texto":"Esto es\n un hola mundo"
        }
    ]
 }
```

y cuando lo representes en tu `TextView` usa el método `Html.fromHtml(...)` para obtener la representación html y se despliegue en negritas lo contenido entre `<b>` y `</b>` :

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(respuesta));
```

Si no se tiene la posibilidad de modificar la respuesta entonces usa un [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) definiendo un [StyleSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html):

```
respuesta = "Hola mundo Esto es un hola mundo";
SpannableString miTexto = new SpannableString(strTexto);
    StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    miTexto.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, 10, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(miTexto);
```

de esta forma obtendrías:

**Hola mundo**: Esto es un hola mundo

---

Pregunta relacionada:

[Negrita en una parte de un TextView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34401/negrita-en-una-parte-de-un-textview)