# Texto en negrita y normal en un item de un array

Tags: android, array, string

buenas a todos. Estoy intentando implementar una idea que quizás no sea realizable, puesto que no encuentro ninguna información por ningún sitio.

Yo tengo un array con varios items, mi idea es que los strings de esos items aparezca la primera palabra del mismo en negrita y las siguientes normales. He pensado en algún caracter tipo /n que pase la letra de negrita a normal, pero no lo encuentro.

¿Se os ocurre algo) La idea es:

```
<array name="array_nom">
        <item>**Gómez** Manuel</item>
        <item>**Pérez** Luis</item>
</array>
```

**->palabra en negrita

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto fue preguntado en el sitio, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34401/negrita-en-una-parte-de-un-textview como que no encontraste información en ninguno, este es el bueno :)

Comment: @Jorgesys me da error cuando lo pongo asi:    <item> <![CDATA[<b>Gómez</b> Manuel]]> <item>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la etiqueta `<b></b>` que sirve para marcar el texto en negrita en un `TextView`:

```
<array name="array_nom">
        <item><b>Gómez</b> Manuel</item>
        <item><b>Pérez</b> Luis</item>
</array>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona bien!!